# Can Methods in OuterClass can invoke only static methods in the static InnerClass?

Tags: java

This was a question i got recently - multi choice, but im struggling to see why 5 is not part of the answer.. The correct answer is (2,4) but i picked (2,4,5)...

1) Methods in InnerClass have a direct access to all the fields of OuterClass

2) Methods in InnerClass have a direct access to the static fields of OuterClass

3) Methods in InnerClass can invoke any method in the OuterClass

4) Methods in InnerClass can invoke only static methods in the OuterClass

5) Methods in OuterClass can invoke only static methods in the InnerClass

```
public class OuterClass {
      private int value;
      private static class InnerClass {
        // inner class methods
      }
      // outer class methods
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you interpret it. The code `InnerClass.nonStaticMethod()` won't work, since you need to create an instance of the class. If this is meant, 5 would be correct. But it looks like the question meant if this code was possible: `innerClassInstance.nonStaticMethod()` In this case 5 is wrong since every class can call a public non-static method through an instance of the class.

Comment: Outerclass can call Inner class methods if an instance of Inner exists. Which makes 5 wrong... but then why is 4 correct, because Inner can also call OuterClass non static methods with an instance.

Comment: @user1555190 So there are two possible solutions: (2) or (2,4,5), but for some reason only (2,4) is correct... I think there is some error in the question! Maybe OP misread something or poorly translated some of the options.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is much more accurate to see that 5 is wrong

```
public class OuterClass 
{
  private int value;
  private static String s2="outterString_2";
  public String s3="outterString_3";
  private String msg = "to be set";
  private String getMsg()
  {
      return msg;
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
      System.out.println(new OuterClass.InnerClass().out("non_static_Inner method access from Outers"));
      System.out.println(new OuterClass.InnerClass().out2());
      System.out.println(new OuterClass.InnerClass().out3());
      OuterClass o = new OuterClass();
      InnerClass i = new OuterClass.InnerClass(o);
      o.msg="new Message";        
      System.out.println(i.o.getMsg());


  }
  private static class InnerClass
  {
    public OuterClass o=null;  
    InnerClass()
    {

    }
    InnerClass(OuterClass o)
    {
        this.o = o;
    }
    public String out(String s)
    {
        return s;
    }
    public String out2()
    {
        return OuterClass.s2;
    }
    public String out3()
    {
        return new OuterClass().s3;
    }
  }
}
```

Output
`non_static_Inner method accessed from Outers`
`outterString_2`
`outterString_3`
`new Message` - set before on o_instance

Comment: depends of how is invoked. With an instance of `Outter` get what ever you can from object. So I say also YES, 4_wrong

Comment: Further more `Inner` can have a constructor to pass a specific instance of `Outter` ... so again access what ever is allowed from `Outter`